# SQL server 2008 running large query - out of memory

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, import, sql-server-express

I've got a 140mb SQL query to import data to a new database.  I file > open the query, and try and execute it but I get:

`Exception of type'System.outofmemoryexception' was thrown. (mscorlib)`

I got 8gb ram, using <3gb so what can I do?

```
   at System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder..ctor(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni(IntPtr ptr)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ShellTextBuffer.GetText(Int32 startPosition, Int32 chars)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ShellTextBuffer.get_Text()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ShellCodeWindowControl.GetSelectedTextSpan()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptEditorControl.GetSelectedTextSpan()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptAndResultsEditorControl.OnExecScript(Object sender, EventArgs a)
```

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      10.50.1600.1
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7600.16385
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.0.8112.16421
Microsoft .NET Framework                        2.0.50727.4952
Operating System                        6.1.7600
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're running in Management Studio Express?

Comment: SQL Management Studio 10.50.1600.1

Comment: What's the stack trace of the error? Do you have any SSMS addins installed?

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server are you running (express, enterprise, etc)?  http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx

Comment: It's express, that's a 1GB limit then? That might explain it.

Comment: @Tom - [Looks like a bug/limitation of SSMS](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/269566/sql-server-management-studio-cant-handle-large-files). No workarounds listed there to get it to work in SSMS itself. I guess you could use `osql`, `sqlcmd` or an alternative utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue reported on Microsoft Connect:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/269566/sql-server-management-studio-cant-handle-large-files

If you take a look you can see some workarounds such as using SQL CMD to execute and editing in Notepad++.

It does not appear they will be fixing this however.